# iPhone, app release, change device requirements

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I have released an app in the appstore months ago.
It was first made only for iPhone (because I wanted to do so), now I would like to release it also for the iPod Touch.

What I have to do to make the iphone app available to ipod touch too?

When I update the app (new version tested on the ipod) I cannot change the value of the dropdown labeled "Device Requirements"

I don't want to make another app with the same content and same code just to change that value!

Many thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've come to a solution releasing an update of the app.

Comment: If you find a solution to your own problem, you should at least post it here. Writing "I has solutions!" and marking the answer as accepted looks really >.<

Answer (score 0):

I would contact Apple Developer Support and tell them you would like the change.  In many cases, they can override things like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is weird. Anyway, besides contacting the support, bear in mind that you also need to modify your -info.plist file adding the "Required device capabilities" (UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities) key.

Basically, you define here what kind of hardware your application uses, such as wifi, core location, compass, accelerometer etc. This is then used to automatically distinguish a device capable of running your app from another which is not.

This is not yet mandatory, but Apple will warn you if you submit an application targeting the iPhone and iPod Touch 2nd generation without a properly configured plist file.